# Read data or import data

Tags: c++, c, database

I'm writing small program. Program use data from other software. That other software keep data in Sysbase SQL db. To keep my data I'm using SQLite. ATM it looks like that: I read data from SysbaseSQL (id, art_id, name, ...) and then I write data to sqlite (id, art_id, amount).
When I show data, I read from Sysbase (id, art_id, name, ..) and sqlite (amount).

But I think that maybe I should import data (when my program starting) from Sysbase to sqlite (id, art_id, name, ...) and make operations only on sqlite.

Which way is proper?

ps. sorry for my english

Comment: Where does the 'amount' come from - is it calculated by your program based on the data from Sybase? Is there any reason you need to store this in another database, instead of calculating it only when necessary?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, because the important thing is the update mechanism in databases, if you import data to SQLite, you will make duplications. As I understand from SQlite usage, you do not need to share stored data, which is specific to your application. Therefore, separate usage seems OK. But, if Sysbase SQL db is read-only and no update occurs during run-time, for the sake of performance you may import data to SQLite.